# deleting first node from singly linked list Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I have a linked list data structure and I am testing the deleteInfo() function. However, when I try to delete the last item in the linked list, I get an error. The linked list grows by inserting from the top so the last item in this case is actually the first item that was inserted.

Here is the code:

```
public lList deleteInfo(String outInfo) {
        if ( info == outInfo ) {
            lList link = nextList().deleteInfo( outInfo );
            info = link.info;
            nextList = link.nextList();
        }
        else if ( nextList() != null )
            nextList().deleteInfo( outInfo );
        return this;
    }

public void insert(String in_Info) {
        if ( isEmpty() == false ) {
            lList entry = new lList(); // New entry is created to store new list
            entry.info = info; //Store the current list's information into this list
            entry.nextList = nextList;
            nextList = entry; //Next list now points to the entry created
        }

        info = in_Info;
    }

public lList nextList() {
        if ( isEmpty() == false )
            return nextList;
        return null;
    }
```

Can someone show me a way to allow for deleting the last list? I know the problem is in the first if statement because it might be trying to access a null list because the last list has no nextList. But I know no other ways of doing this; so any help is appreciated

Comment: This snippit on its own makes absolutely no sense. It almost looks like you're trying to delete a node from within a node.

Comment: Yes Brian this is exactly what I am trying to do, but not deleting the node. I am simply linking changing the data it contains to that of the next node after it that does not contain the same data as it does

Comment: The problem you're going to have with that is that you can't delete yourself. What if you only had one node?

Comment: That is what my problem is. This is easy to accomplish without using recursion and using a simple for-loop instead, but the prof said that most of the methods can be written using recursion and that is why I want to try

Comment: Right - so, you *can* do it like this recursively, but you're going to have to pass in a reference to the previous node as this is a singly linked list. To delete a node you need a reference to the previous node and a reference to the next node. Or ... look two nodes ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public lList deleteInfo(String outInfo) {
        if ( nextList() != null && nextList().info == outInfo ) {
            lList link = nextList();

            nextList = link.nextList();
        }
        else if (nextList() != null){
            nextList().deleteInfo( outInfo );
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Your method will ignore the last entry in the linked list if it contained the info being sought

Comment: @Smac89 no... It will work for last node.. basically in my code we are deleting next node.. not current node..so if  `nextList()==null` then you are at end of list with no matching element.

Comment: so if last element has the data... the second last element `if ( nextList() != null && nextList().info == outInfo ) {` will be true... and `second last nextelement will be set to null`

Comment: No, I just tried it, it does not even "delete" the node it is supposed to and instead "deletes" the wrong one

Comment: @Smac89 check updated answer `removed info=nextList().info`

Comment: Sicckkk! Dude you are baws! Thank you soo much!

Comment: Ahh, but it doesn't work with one item in the list and that is the one you are trying to delete. But I guess that is a good thing? Because if you delete it, you will not have access to the list anymore. Thanks again dude

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add an inner if into the first if checking that if you're deleting the last or not:

```
 public lList deleteInfo(String outInfo) {
        if ( info == outInfo ) {
         if( nextList() == null ) {
               //delete current list as u want
               return this;
         }
            lList link = nextList().deleteInfo( outInfo );
            info = link.info;
            nextList = link.nextList();
        }
        else if ( nextList() != null )
            nextList().deleteInfo( outInfo );
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: This will still have the last item in the linked list if it contained the info

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked for me:

```
//lList : deleteInfo()
//Pre: information to delete
//Post : List not containing information is returned
public lList deleteInfo(String outInfo) {
    if ( nextList() != null ) {
        lList link = nextList().deleteInfo( outInfo );
        if ( nextList().info == outInfo ) { //Handles information that is located at end of list
            nextList = link.nextList();
        }
        else if ( info == outInfo ){//Handles information that is located at beginning of list
            info = link.info;
            nextList = link.nextList();
        }
        else nextList().deleteInfo( outInfo );
    }
    return this;
}
```

Note it does not work when there is only one list and you are trying to delete the information in that list. I think that is a good thing because you cannot dereference self